# What version scheme is this alpine version following?

Tags: linux, docker, versioning, alpine-linux, semantic-versioning

I was playing around with a script that allows me to find out the OS version of docker images. Trying the latter on `alpine:edge` returned this `3.13.0_alpha20200626`.

Printing /etc/os-release outputs the following

```sh
/ # cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.13.0_alpha20200626
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux edge"
HOME_URL="https://alpinelinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/"
```

Surely this version would not validate as [SemVer](https://semver.org/). What version scheme is this alpine version following?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Alpine `edge` is always under development so that is why the version ID contains the date, while for the stable release it will contain standard `version ID` with **pretty Name**.

**Warning**: "**edge" is under constant development** so be careful using it in production. It is possible that bugs in "edge" could cause data loss or could break your system.

[alpine edge](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Edge)

So you should  relay on **pretty name** instead of version ID.
docker tag refer to version ID for example the tag is `alpine:3.7.3` then the ID will be `3.7.3`

I did not find any official documentation but here is something can help you

```
VERSION_ID=3.{Major}.{minor}
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux 3.{Major}"
```

**So pretty name will always refer the major version, no mater whats the minor version is**

```
alpine:3.7.3 ---> PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.7"
alpine:3.8 ---> PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.8"
alpine:3.9 ---> PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.9"
```

while this is different for edge releases.

```
VERSION_ID=3.{CURRENT_MAJOR}_alpha{SNAPSHOT_DATE}
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux {edge}"
```

> **Stable releases** are just what they sound like: initially a **point-in-time snapshot** of the package archives, but then maintained with bug-fixes only in order to keep a stable environment.

> **Edge** is more of a rolling-release, with the latest and greatest packages available in the online repositories.

[What_is_the_difference_between_edge_and_stable_releases](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux:FAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_edge_and_stable_releases.3F)